# マクロを使うと、数式に@がついて、エラーになる。

Tags: excel

```
{=INDEX(result!N:Q,MATCH(B13&CE13,result!A:A&result!Q:Q,0),1)}
```

上記、index matchの複数条件の式で、B13、CE13にある値を検索値に、「result」シートから値を取り出すという関数を組みました。この時点ではエラーは出ず、式は期待通りの値を拾ってきます。

上記の式を、マクロにて、ローデータが存在する行分コピーするという処理を行います。

```
=INDEX(result!N:Q,MATCH(B13&CE13,@result!A:A&@result!Q:Q,0),1)
```

しかし、関数をコピーするマクロを回すと、
すべての行で上記の「@」がついた式に変換され、エラーになってしまいます。

原因の見当は付きますでしょうか。
また、index matchを複数条件で行うほかの方法などあればアドバイスいただきたいです。

Comment: 『コピーするという処理』で`Range("A1").Formula = ...`のように`Formula`プロパティで操作をしていませんか？その場合は[`Formula2`に書き換える](http://www.excel.studio-kazu.jp/kw/20201121171340.html)ことで解決可能かもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！いただいたリンクに記載のあったXLOOKUP関数を使用することで解決しました！確かにFormulaプロパティ使用しておりましたが、Formula2にすると関数が絶対参照のような挙動になり、同じセルを参照する状態でコピーされました・・・。この度はありがとうございました！